# How to fetch and insert more data with Inertia

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, inertiajs

I'm working a logs view that fetches logs from aws cloudwatch. The Vue template would simply be a table with a date and the log messages.

I would like to have the table work like it's tailing the logs. On the first load, it gets the last 30 mins of logs or whatever. It would then poll every 5 seconds and fetch more logs and show the logs at the top of the table.

For the tailing/polling piece, I know that I can simply create a timeout to call a fetchMoreLogs function and insert the newer logs at the front of the logs array, but is there another way to do this that is more in line with Inertia and partial page loading?

Also, my current implementation resets the scroll to the top of the page after the new logs are inserted.

```
<script setup>
import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue";
import { Head } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
import { router } from "@inertiajs/vue3";

Head.name = "InertiaHead";

const props = defineProps({
    logs: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
    },
    nextForwardToken: {
        type: String,
    }
});
let logs = ref(props.logs);
let nextForwardToken = ref(props.nextForwardToken);

const logCount = computed(() => {
  return logs.value ? logs.value.length : 0;
});

const convertToClientLocalTime = (timestamp) => {
    const localDate = new Date(timestamp);
    return localDate.toLocaleString(); // You can customize this based on your needs
};


const fetchMoreLogs = () => {
  router.get('/logs', { nextForwardToken: nextForwardToken.value }, {
    preserveState: true,
    onSuccess: (page) => {
      if (page.props.logs && page.props.logs.length > 0) {
        // Insert new logs in the beginning
        logs.value = [...newLogs, ...logs.value];
   
        nextForwardToken.value = page.props.nextForwardToken;
      }
      // Run again
      setTimeout(fetchMoreLogs, 5000);
    },
  });
}

// Run once
setTimeout(fetchMoreLogs, 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current approach using a setTimeout to periodically fetch more logs and insert them at the beginning of the logs array is a reasonable way to implement log tailing. However, if you want to make it more in line with Inertia and partial page loading, you can consider using Inertia's built-in feature for partial updates, which allows you to load new data without a full page reload.

Here's how you can modify your implementation to use Inertia's partial updates:

Make sure you have set up your Inertia routes and controller to handle partial updates for logs. This typically involves creating a separate route and controller method for fetching logs.

Modify your fetchMoreLogs function to use Inertia's visit method to load new logs:

```
const fetchMoreLogs = () => {
  const payload = { nextForwardToken: nextForwardToken.value };
  Inertia.visit(route("logs.fetch"), {
    data: payload,
    replace: false, // Allows you to append data to the current page
    preserveState: true,
    onSuccess: (page) => {
      if (page.props.logs && page.props.logs.length > 0) {
        // Insert new logs in the beginning
        logs.value = [...page.props.logs, ...logs.value];
        nextForwardToken.value = page.props.nextForwardToken;
      }
      // Run again
      setTimeout(fetchMoreLogs, 5000);
    },
  });
};

// Run once
setTimeout(fetchMoreLogs, 5000);
```